# Does NetBeans have a standard area for plugin configuration files?

Tags: java, netbeans, config

I am developing a plugin for NetBeans IDE 8.1 and I need to store persistent preferences to a file on disk, is there a standard location in NetBeans to store configuration files for plugins? And if there is such a place then what's the easiest way of defining it (as the NetBeans could be installed anywhere, especially depending on the OS)? Is there a special method or something which allows one to easily specify the location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Netbeans API defines the concept of the [SystemFileSystem](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqSystemFilesystem) which is basically the *config* subfolder of your user directory. *You're not supposed to directly place files there*.

Netbeans provides both an annotation and file-based configuration deployment mechanism. For the file-based approach (what you're interested in), you're supposed to bundle the config file as an XML file, known as a [layer file](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqModulesLayerFile), and then define this file in your module's manifest. In doing this, the System Filesystem will create a subfolder in the config folder named for your module, containing whatever you define (NB defines a fairly robust and elaborate configuration management framework for modules).

An excerpt from the documentation:

> - In your JAR, provide the layer file - e.g. com/foo/mymodule/resources/layer.xml
> - In your module's manifest, include the following line somewhere in the top section:
>
> `OpenIDE-Module-Layer: com/foo/mymodule/resources/layer.xml`

**Bottom Line:** Bundle your config files *inside* your module jar. The API will handle the rest

Related reading:

- [How can netbeans modules install things](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansDeveloperFAQ#Configuration:_How_Modules_Install_Things)
- [Ways a netbeans module can influence the system](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqModulesGeneral)
- [What is the System Filesystem](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqSystemFilesystem)
- [What is a layer file](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqModulesLayerFile)
- [Declarative vs Programmatic module configuration](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqModulesDeclarativeVsProgrammatic)

Comment: I've ended up using the NbPreferences API. Is that the same thing? Because I can't seem to figure out where it is storing stuff so either you could point me in the right direction, or I post a new question if they are different. It's been such a while I just don't remember.

Comment: I don't follow @ParanoidPanda - are you saying this answer didn't work for you? Bundling your files with the plugin jar doesn't work?

Comment: I think that I ended up not being able to do that and finding out that the way NetBeans now wants you to do it is with the NbPreferences API. I don't know, I thought I found it through your links, maybe it's an automated way of doing what you said? I'm really not sure, I haven't looked at the code in a while and I've just come back to do some maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Anything an individual user adds should go into the individual user's home directory (~/ on *nix and c:\users\username on windows) and then in a subdirectory with appropriate name.  Netbeans does this (as does just about every other app that can be configured by the end user) - any Linux user will see it at ~/.netbeans/versionnumber

Check out http://wiki.netbeans.org/UserdirAndCachedirFoldersInSystemSpecificPaths

Comment: I see that there is a `config` folder in there, so should I just get it to create its own file and folder in there or is there somewhere special in there where I am meant to do it? Also, is there no way of specifying the location without having to specify the whole path? Does NetBeans not somehow know and have the ability to tell you where its configurations folder is stored? I would imagine it would know, so if they have somewhere they expect you to store configuration files then I would expect them to allow your code to ask it somehow.

Comment: I've never written a plugin for netbeans, but the developer documentation mentions what to reference on this page http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqUserDir